# Equilavent of WebAuthenticationResult Windows Phone?

Tags: facebook, authentication, windows-phone-8

I am using Facebook API authentication in my windows store client app..
I want to use same code in my WP8 client  app. I have just copied and pasted the code.
There was only two errors.

```
WebAuthenticationResult and WebAuthenticationBroker
```

I don't want to change my code. Is there any equivalent for this classes in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: by using a class named "PhoneWebAuthentication.cs" I guess I will solve the compatibility problem.. Code and link is below.

Comment: I cant share code please see and confirm my solution and tell me if I am on wrong way..

Comment: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook.Client/PhoneWebAuthentication.cs